# SpellCheck Functionality in Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, spell-checking

I have an issue in Spellchecking the text that is entered in a textbox in wpf 3.5

```
<TextBox Name="tbxBack"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
```

It will Check fine for the wrongly spell words in the sentence that I have entered in the text box, but when I right click on the wrongly spell word and try to make correct, it is only making the first word correct in the sentence.

for example:

**the sentence is**:

*tey are plaing in playgroun* (**They are playing in playground**)

when I right click on "tey", system is giving the appropriate results and setting the correct value ("**They**" for "**tey**"),

but when I right click on "**plaing**", system gives the correct values, but does not set it to correctvalue ("**playing**").

same for "**playgroun**" (doesn't set to **playground**), System is checking only the first word.

How to make it work for the whole sentence?

Comment: Works fine for me, tried with your phrase *"tey are plaing in playgroun"* and the correction worked for every word. The problem is probably something else